# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray and vice versa?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to read a json object (or array, tbh I'm not sure what the hell this is). 
Anyway, I shall point out that I started working with json arrays yesterday so sorry if this is a simple question.

Here's what happens:

```
//doesn’t work

JSONArray valarray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Gives this error: `type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

```
//works

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

Log.v("RESULTS" , jsonObject.get("results").toString());
```

```
//Doesn’t work

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

JSONObject resultsObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
```

Gives this error: `type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "results" : [
    {
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 50.6,
          "lng" : -0.00
        }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "242c6a9664ca28a2",
      "name" : "whatever",
      "place_id" : "ChIJ6xum8T",
      "reference" : "CoQBdQAAAIp",
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "establishment" ],
      "vicinity" : "United Kingdom"
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

How am I suppose to get the `lat` and `lng` inside of `geometry` for example?

Comment: I reformatted your JSON so you can see the various levels easier.

Comment: You cannot convert an JSON object to a JSON array, or vice-versa.  They are different things.  Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: And be sure to the Java-specific documentation at http://www.json.org/java/.

Comment: `lat` and `lng` aren't (directly) inside `geometry`.  They are inside the object `location`, which is inside the object `geometry` which is inside an object that is the zeroth element of the array `results`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Wrong!!  That will not teach him the JSON syntax.

Comment: @HotLicks: Perhaps not, but it will tell him how Java accesses the different data types at each level of the hierarchy. Obviously, he needs to know how to read the JSON syntax to understand which data type is being used at each level. And my earlier comment did start with `And`. I was not precluding your comment to read the syntax documentation at http://www.json.org, I was merely stating to **also** read the Java documentation that goes with it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - No, that's just one of many ways.  There are about 20 different JSON packages for Java (not counting the Android version I threw together about 4 years ago).  One needs to understand JSON itself, then understand how any given toolkit maps that to Java objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON consists of an `object`.  That `object` contains an array named `results`. The array contains `object` elements.  Each `object` in the array contains an `object` named `geometry`.  That object contains an `object` named `location`.  That `object` contains `lat` and `lng` floating-point values.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
String json = ...;
JSONObject JsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray ResultArr = JsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject ResultObj = ResultArr.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject Geometry = ResultObj.getJSONObject("geometry");
JSONObject Location = Geometry.getJSONObject("location");
double Latitude = Location.getDouble("lat");
double Longitude = Location.getDouble("lng");
```

Since you are dealing with an array, you can iterate through it like this:

```
String json = ...;
JSONObject JsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray ResultArr = JsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
int count = ResultArr.length();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    JSONObject ResultObj = ResultArr.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject Geometry = ResultObj.getJSONObject("geometry");
    JSONObject Location = Geometry.getJSONObject("location");
    double Latitude = Location.getDouble("lat");
    double Longitude = Location.getDouble("lng");
    //...
}
```